# How to activate a Conda environment in a custom working directory?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

Suppose I have a project for which I create a Conda environment in Windows, when I activate the environment, the working directory always is my user folder. I need to change my directory every time to my project folder. Is there a way to specify the default directory when I activate a Conda environment?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the --prefix flag. ie:

```
conda create --prefix /some/folder/far/far/away python=3.6
```

Will create the environment named away in folder /some/folder/far/far .

Answer (score 1):

You can create a script for your environment that is run when you do `conda activate <your env>` and then put a `cd` command in there:

Example:

```
(base) C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3>conda activate test

(test) C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3>cd %CONDA_PREFIX%

(test) C:\Users\<myUsername>\.conda\envs\test>mkdir .\etc\conda\activate.d

(test) C:\Users\<myUsername>\.conda\envs\test>mkdir .\etc\conda\deactivate.d

(test) C:\Users\<myUsername>\.conda\envs\test>type NUL > .\etc\conda\activate.d\env_vars.bat

(test) C:\Users\<myUsername>\.conda\envs\test>type NUL > .\etc\conda\deactivate.d\env_vars.bat
```

Now I edited the file `.\etc\conda\activate.d\env_vars.bat` to include this:

```
cd C:\
```

Then, when I activate the environment:

```
(base) C:\Users\a-fjochhe\.conda\envs\test>conda activate test

C:\Users\a-fjochhe\.conda\envs\test>cd C:\    <--- This happens automatically

(test) C:\>   <---- Now I am in C:\ directory
```

You can modify the script in `.\etc\conda\activate.d` to `cd` into your working directory

Answer (score 0):

You can change the working directory by setting the PWD env variable on Linux. Conda has an option to push env. variables on activation.
Here is an example to cd to ~/my-project on activation of the environment 'my'.

```
conda env config vars set PWD=$HOME/my-project -n my
```

This might also work on windows where the current working directory is stored in the %CD% variable but I haven't tried that.

Note, it will show a warning each time you switch an env saying:

> WARNING: overwriting environment variables set in the machine
> overwriting variable PWD

Comment: more on the subject here: https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html